# What happens to the blood that gets on the T-1000?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

When the T-1000 slays someone, as it does John's stepfather or the trucker, does the blood from its victims get absorbed into the terminator's body, or is it eliminated somehow?

Comment: Interesting question. Several times we see the T-1000 kill someone & get blood on itself, then minutes later there's no blood. My best guess (not really an answer) is that it makes its surface slick enough that the blood just runs right off onto the floor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't addressed in the **film** (on the three occasions when the T-1000 kills with a bladed weapon, the blood simply disappears when it turns back into its policeman form), nor the **novelisation** (there's no mention of the blood being absorbed or dripped whatsoever) **nor** the script:

> **The spike is withdrawn -- SWIISHHTT! -- so rapidly, Todd is actually
>           standing there a second before he slumps out of sight. THUMP. Janelle doesn't bat an eye as the spike smoothly changes shape and
>           color, transforming back into a hand, and then JANELLE CHANGES rapidly into the COP we now know as the T-1000.  The change has liquid
>   quality.**

Since the T-1000 can apparently make its metal skin non-porous it seems likely that the blood simply dropped onto the floor when it changed back into its base state.

Comment: I also checked T-3 to see if the Terminatrix did anything clever with the blood. Aside from licking it, there aren't any scenes that apply.